# jQuery AJAX InProgress

Tags: php, html, ajax, jquery

So I have a password recovery option setup on the main page of my website that uses swift mailer to email the user with their new password. The user enters in his/her email into a box and the main page sends an AJAX request to the php script. All of that works but when you hit send, it takes a while before the php script sends a response back saying `New password successfully sent to email`. I don't want the user clicking send again and again thinking the first click didn't go through. Is there a way to disable the send button along with displaying some sort of loading bar while ajax is waiting for the script's response? Thanks

Comment: There are many ways.  Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Yes, yes there is a way. Which way have you tried?

Comment: @JamesMontagne that's why i'm posting here, I don't really know where to start. Can I just use ajax's inprogress function and inside of that use jquery selector to select the button and then use the css method to disable it? Meanwhile also `.show()` the progress bar? But how can i link the progress bar to the actual progress of the script?

Comment: @Richard, You're in the right place to ask :) People, don't you remember when you first started and didn't know which direction to turn or what question to ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manually doing it, use JQuery ajaxStart and ajaxStop functions.

```
$('#progress').ajaxStart(function () {
 //disable the button
 $(this).show();
}).ajaxStop(function () {
 //enable the button
 $(this).hide();
});
```

Note: It get shows up for every JQuery AJAX operation on the page.

Answer (score 1):

you could disable the button once it's clicked and then re-enable it when the ajax completes.

so before calling the ajax do something like:

```
 $("#MyBtn").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

then once the AJAX has finished, remove the attribute

```
$("#MyBtn").removeAttr("disabled");
```

you could also have a div that's hidden then show/hide it..

I.E

```
<div id="divWait" style="display:none;">Please Wait...</div>
```

Your code above would now be

so before the ajax call:

```
 $("#MyBtn").attr("disabled", "disabled");
 $("divWait").show();
```

When AJAX finishes...

```
$("#MyBtn").removeAttr("disabled");   
$("#divWait").hide();
```

What's more, depending on the result of the AJAX call you could change the text inside the div too.

So.. if it works don't hide the div, just change the text:

```
$("#divWait").html("Your password was sent..");
```

And if it fails, hide the div like above, or change the message

```
 $("#divWait").html("oops, there was a booboo");
```